# JMS single message acknowledge on consumer choice

Tags: transactions, jms

Consider the following scenario with a JMS Queue: we have a JMS broker B with Queue Q and MessageConsumer C1 created with Session S1. C1 receives messages M1, M2, M3 with onMessage() method invocation (async) and starts threads T1, T2, T3 in order to process M1, M2, M3 (respectively) in parallel. We do not know how much time it takes to complete any of T1, T2, T3. At some point in time T2 is the first thread to complete execution: is it possible to acknowledge (or commit) just M2 to the broker B in such a way that if session S1 is closed soon afterward, then M1 and M3 will be kept by B and re-delivered to another session S2 and another consumer C2?

Session.CLIENT_ACK is not what we need, SINGLE_ACK of some JMS implementations may be what I am looking for, but it is not JMS standard. Perhaps JMS transactions can solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

The `Message` interface defines `acknowledge` which allows for acknowledging single messages. So you could just call `message.acknowledge` in T2.

As a side note: your onMessage() callback might already be called from multiple Threads, depending on your JMS provider's implementation.

Comment: acknowledge methods acknowledges all consumed messages for given session